# PHP: Class instantiation in static property throws exception

Tags: php, arrays, static-members

I'd like to create a class (e.g. `Bar`) which has a private static property. This property should be an array of objects of `Foo`.

```
<?php

class Foo {

}

class Bar {
    private static $classes = array(new Foo(), new Foo());

    public static function testClasses() {
        var_dump(self:$classes);
    }
}

Bar::testClasses();
```

However this code throws an exception:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW), expecting ')' in [...]/test.php on line 8
```

Can somebody explain me why this is not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Your use of new to instantiate the classes in the property definition Is dependent on run-time information